# Are there any characters that would cause problems in sending an SMS?

Tags: android

are there any characters that, if included in an SMS message (body), might cause problems with being sent?

edit: Actually I only care really about any characters that can be input by user with keyboard (but in any language).. don't know if that makes my question easier to answer or not...

Comment: Seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186702/looking-for-a-list-of-valid-characters-that-can-be-sent-in-sms-text-messages

Comment: thanks I saw that... just was wondering if it was different in Android, like maybe android does something to the message to remove invalid characters before sending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straightforward answer to this as it depends on a variety of factors, but this standard lays out the basics and I expect you can use this to deduce which characters to focus on:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38

I would advise doing extensive testing of the characters you use, on different handsets, and in your target locales.