# Extended characters in GSM

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, gsm, extended-ascii, asciiencoding

I'm doing a project which requires me to send a location's geo coordinates through SMS. I'm building my system around a PIC microcontroller (PIC1 8F26K22), and interfaced (almost) successfully the GPS and GSM modules.

The only problem I'm facing is that, I am unable to send the degree symbol ° (0xF8) through SMS. When sending the string from the controller to the GSM, I send it as F8 (hex value of °), but the received SMS shows it as @ instead of °.

It must be something to do with encoding in the GSM module I believe. Can anyone provide me a solution for it? The GSM that I'm using is SIMCom's Sim800 GSM module.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/5186702 . Change the charset of SMS may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use PDU encoding is you want to use characters like "º". You can set the PDU mode by using this command AT+CMGF=0.